# Measure Voltage with Raspberry Pi? Using a MCP3008?

Tags: raspbian, gpio

I have an MCP3008 ic. I am pretty new to the Raspberry Pi world, as anyone ever used the MCP3008 to simply measure voltage? I just am really not sure how I would go about doing it.

Any advice would be amazing!

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/connecting-the-cobbler-to-a-mcp3008 this can suits the project regarding the views i seen

Answer (score 7):

There is a full guide available with someone making a voltmeter setup [here](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/4553-build-a-digital-voltmeter) - this also includes scripts.
You also can connect it by following the setup detailed [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi) - basically you set up a circuit as so:

[image]

<sup>For testing you can use a potentiometer as shown, you can also use something like a Light Dependent Resistor (LDR) etc</sup>

Install needed packages (may not be needed for some Pi images)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools
sudo easy_install rpi.gpio
```

As for the script, theirs is for a volume control - all you should need to do is connect to the SPI interface and read values. Note with the values:

> The MCP3008 is a 10-bit ADC. That means it will read a value from 0 to
> 1023 (2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 values) where 0 is the same as "ground" and "1023" is
> the same as "3.3 volts".  We don't convert the number to voltage,
> although it's easy to do that by multiplying the number by (3.3 / 1023).

This setup is very limited, as *without modified/extra circuitry* it can't really do voltages outside of 0V to +3.3V, and too high a current could easily fry the chip and or Pi, so you need to be careful what you connect - however it should be suitable for many analog sensors.

Comment: The linked project is certainly a good example to start with.

Comment: You mean too high (or low) a *voltage*?

Comment: First link doesn't work - I think the example was removed