# Voltage Meter with MCP3008

Tags: python, pi-2, hardware

So I am attempting to use an MCP3008 chip to create a Voltage meter with the Raspberry Pi (I have a Pi 2 Model B).  I have been following this tutorial:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-with-python/analogue/

Now I am also using a Breakout Board to do these tests, so I had to make a few changes to the wiring because I don't see the same SPI plug ins on the break-out board as are in the tutorial.  As such I changed the wiring to those described here:

[Measure Voltage with Raspberry Pi? Using a MCP3008?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38406/measure-voltage-with-raspberry-pi-using-a-mcp3008)

From my understanding of the tutorial (first link) after I connect the potentiometer, while I have the program running I should be able to turn it and have the displayed value of my voltage go between 0.0 and 1.0.  However all I am getting at results of 1.0 even when I turn the potentiometer dial as far in each direction as I can.

Does anyone know what my problem could be?  Do I need to do different wiring?  I can provide all the pins the Breakout Board has if you'd like.  Thanks for the help :)

EDIT: I switched the code I am using to the code Adafruit has on their Github

```
# Simple example of reading the MCP3008 analog input channels and printing
# them all out.
# Author: Tony DiCola
# License: Public Domain
import time

# Import SPI library (for hardware SPI) and MCP3008 library.
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MCP3008


# Software SPI configuration:
CLK  = 18
MISO = 23
MOSI = 24
CS   = 25
mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=CLK, cs=CS, miso=MISO, mosi=MOSI)

# Hardware SPI configuration:
# SPI_PORT   = 0
# SPI_DEVICE = 0
# mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE))


print('Reading MCP3008 values, press Ctrl-C to quit...')
# Print nice channel column headers.
print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*range(8)))
print('-' * 57)
# Main program loop.
while True:
    # Read all the ADC channel values in a list.
    values = [0]*8
    for i in range(8):
    # The read_adc function will get the value of the specified channel (0-7).
        values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)
    # Print the ADC values.
    print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*values))
    # Pause for half a second.
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

With this code, I see 1023 as the reading for each of the 8 pins.  When I rotate the potentiometer, nothing happens.  Hell I even removed all the wries from the Breakout board, completely disconnecting the MCP3008 and I was still getting 1023 readings :\

[Update to the photo.  Wiring has been fixed up a bit, however it is still not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBAFO.jpg)

I have to Pins connected as follows to the labelled Pins o nthe Breakout Board:

```
Pin 9 (VDD) -> 3V3
Pin 10 (VREF) -> 3V3
Pin 11 (AGND) -> GND
Pin 12 (CLK) -> SCLK
Pin 13 (DOUT) -> MISO
Pin 14 (DIN) -> MOSI
Pin 15 (CS) -> CE0
Pin 16 (DGND) -> GND
```

EDIT 2: The potentiometer I am using is a B50K which has a power rating of 0.125W

Comment: Can you please provide an image of your specific physical layout? Editing your question with your code may shed some light on the problem as well.

Comment: Best to say what rating of Potentiometer you're using, too.

Comment: @stevieb Just editted to add the code and a picture of the wiring :)

Comment: @recantha It's a B50K, just added that to the OP as well

Comment: Leaving the pot in the image may have helped. Perhaps you simply had it wired incorrectly.

Comment: It looks like your wiring is wrong. This should match the breakout board (not necessarily the names but the locations) https://pinout.xyz/. You also should use red for VCC and blue for ground on the ground rails - you have the reverse.

Comment: @SteveRobillard With concerns to the the VCC & GND I have the wiring plugged in where the breakout board says each of those are.  I'll try to rework my wiring and see if that helps

Comment: @stevieb I'll add a picture with the pot momentarily

Comment: It isn't the VCC and ground connections at the breakout board that I was referring to. It is the breadboard power rails (the outer two rows on each side) that have a red and blue line that you have backwards. If you look at pin 16 which should go to VCC is connected to the blue rail on the left and pin 0 which goes to ground is connected to the red rail on the right. Mixing the colors can make debugging harder.

Comment: The SPI pins are wrong as well as they should be 4 pins 2 on each side of the breakout board about half way down the breakout board and at least mosi is labeled. on the left side of the breakout.

Comment: @Technico.top I did thanks for catching my mistake.

Comment: On the Pi the specific pins are setup for SPI communication, you can't just change them at random.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I just made a big edit to the OP. I changed the code I was using, fixed up the wiring (I think) and included where I am putting what pins wiring based on what I can read off of the Breakout Board.  I also noticed that I can completely disconnect all the wires from the MCP3008, and yet the program still registers a voltage reading.  Yet when I unplug the ribbon cable from the Pi, then the voltage hits 0.

Comment: Try it with a 10K potentiometer. When I built a project, I used a 1K and it didn't work - very similar behaviour to your description - when I changed to 10K it suddenly worked. Worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wiing looks right now.

Try this code:

```
from gpiozero import MCP3008
from time import sleep 
pot = MCP3008(0)

while True:
    print(pot.value)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks.  So I think my problem might actually be the Breakout Board.  I noticed the ADC seemed to be heating up when I had it plugged in so I ran the beard board's lines through a volt tester and it turns out the 5V & GND were the reverse of what was labelled (with the GND actually carrying the voltage) and on the 3.3V end I'm only getting about 1.79V through.  Might I have to get a new Breakout Board?

Comment: I doubt the board is wrong. On the ribbon cable, there should be a stripe. the end of the cable with the stripe goes towards the sd card end of the Pi. You may well have fried your ADC.  Can you post an additional pick showing the ribbon cable connections?

Comment: [It's kind of hard to tell if there's a stripe on this cable.....](http://imgur.com/a/Kuyo6)

Comment: Yeah, sorry mine are a solid color, not a rainbow. So try this, plug the cable into the board and measure the voltage at the 3.3 and ground pins on the breakout board (disconnect or remove the ADC first) if you don't get 3.3 volts and the right polarity reverse the cable and try again. Also, there should be only one way to plug it in at the breakout board because of the matching lug and notch.

Comment: So yeah, I had the ribbon cable in backwards.  The way it's set up is so weird.  The ribbon cable runs over top of the breakout board, as opposed to away from it.  This won't be annoying at all to work with :P

Comment: Can you post a pic? There is usually a way to run the cable so that does not happen. Have you retried your ADC?

Comment: I retried the ADC and it's working now.  Just need to remember the math to get it from the 0.0 - 1.0 value to a voltage

Comment: voltage = (pot.value * 3.3)