# Issues using SPI pins on Raspberry Pi 3 with MCP3008 ADC for Voltage Sensor

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sensor, troubleshooting, voltage

I am trying to create a voltage sensor using a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian  (February 2017 release because that is the one I need for the rest of my project) by connecting the SPI pins to an MCP3008 ADC, but when I try to run this code (http://osoyoo.com/driver/voltage.py), I always get an output of 0.00 V. I followed the tutorial where this code came from:

(http://kookye.com/2017/06/01/design-a-voltmeter-with-the-raspberry-pi-board-and-voltage-sensor/)

I have tried using different Pis (a Pi Zero W instead of a 3), different versions of Raspbian, different pins and even different MCP3008 chips but to no avail. I am starting to believe that the SD card or something might be bad because I cannot understand where I am going wrong. I have also tried various other Pi-to-MCP3008 to get something that works, but that hasn't panned out well either. I am really trying to use the software configuration (discussed here: https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/mcp3008)

If anyone could please let me know if there is an issue in the code or circuit design, or if there is some other method I could follow to attain these results, I would be incredibly thankful.

Comment: Did you use the search function... [RPi Exchange: Voltmeter-mcp3008](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68785/voltage-meter-with-mcp3008)

Comment: This is unanswerable (in a useful way) without clear photos of **your** wiring.

Comment: Did you activate the SPI communication by uncomment the line `#dtparam=spi=on` in `/boot/config.txt` to `dtparam=spi=on`? Also need to reboot after the change.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Below is the picture of my circuit. Not shown in the picture is that I have been plugging a wire from the 3.3V line into input CH0 on the MCP3008 as a means of testing.   https://imgur.com/UxdGyGW